# print(pole_a_wid,pole_b_wid) NameError: name 'pole_a_wid' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying something but I ran into a problem ( `NameError: name 'pole_a_wid' is not defined` )
This is my code:

```py
    import random
    #Random Pole Height
    list = [11, 21, 9, 23, 13, 19, 27, 7]
    random_pole_wid = random.choice(list)
    if random_pole_wid == "11":
        pole_a_wid = 11
        pole_b_wid = 21
    elif random_pole_wid == "21":
        pole_a_wid = 21
        pole_b_wid = 11
    elif random_pole_wid == "9":
        pole_a_wid = 9
        pole_b_wid = 23
    elif random_pole_wid == "23":
        pole_a_wid = 23
        pole_b_wid = 9
    elif random_pole_wid == "13":
        pole_a_wid = 13
        pole_b_wid = 19
    elif random_pole_wid == "19":
        pole_a_wid = 19
        pole_b_wid = 13
    elif random_pole_wid == "27":
        pole_a_wid = 27
        pole_b_wid = 7
    elif random_pole_wid == "7":
        pole_a_wid = 7
        pole_b_wid = 27
    
    print(pole_a_wid,pole_b_wid)
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
print(pole_a_wid,pole_b_wid) NameError: name 'pole_a_wid' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an "else" case. All you check is a bunch of if-clauses excluding each other, but your code doesnt assign anything to the values if none of the cases is met.

In this case you have a list containing elements of type `int` but your comparison checks `string`, so all conditions are always wrong.

Use a check like this: `random_pole_wid == 11:` and it will work.

**Edit**: Also generally your code covers 8 cases which are not independent since 4 for them are "mirrored". You could make your code much shorter and more readable like this:

```
import random
# Random Pole Height
lst = [11, 21, 9, 23, 13, 19, 27, 7]  # generally you should avoid overwriting python builtins such as 'list' with your variable names as that can cause hard to debug behaviours!
pole_a_wid = random.choice(lst)

if pole_a_wid in [9, 23, 13, 19]:
    pole_b_wid = 32 - pole_a_wid
elif pole_a_wid in [11, 21]:
    pole_b_wid = 33 - pole_a_wid
elif pole_a_wid in [27, 7]:
    pole_b_wid = 34 - pole_a_wid

print(pole_a_wid, pole_b_wid)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of values contains integers.  But you're checking for string values.

Therefore none of the if statements are true.

Therefore the two variables never get defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your list contains integer values but you're comparing them against strings.

Also, you are testing for `7` twice and not testing for `11`.  When `11` is chosen, you get that same error because you didn't match anything and so those values remain undefined.  You should probably either set the two values to a "default" value before the conditional, or add a final `else` clause to deal with non-matches.  Even if your code should never need that logic, the fact that you've asked this question shows why it makes sense to add such logic...catching code errors explicitly often makes it easier to find and diagnose them.

Here's a modified version of your code that illustrates what I've said above and should behave as you intended:

```
import random
# Random Pole Height
list = [11, 21, 9, 23, 13, 19, 27, 7]
random_pole_wid = random.choice(list)
if random_pole_wid == 11:
    pole_a_wid = 11
    pole_b_wid = 21
elif random_pole_wid == 21:
    pole_a_wid = 21
    pole_b_wid = 11
elif random_pole_wid == 9:
    pole_a_wid = 9
    pole_b_wid = 23
elif random_pole_wid == 23:
    pole_a_wid = 23
    pole_b_wid = 9
elif random_pole_wid == 13:
    pole_a_wid = 13
    pole_b_wid = 19
elif random_pole_wid == 19:
    pole_a_wid = 19
    pole_b_wid = 13
elif random_pole_wid == 27:
    pole_a_wid = 27
    pole_b_wid = 7
elif random_pole_wid == 7:
    pole_a_wid = 7
    pole_b_wid = 27
else:
    print(f"The chosen value '{random_pole_wid}' does not match any of the values being tested for")
    pole_a_wid = 0
    pole_b_wid = 0


print(pole_a_wid, pole_b_wid)
```

A significantly more concise, readable, and maintainable solution would be to create a `dict` to describe your data values and the relationships between them.  The keys of the `dict` would be each of the numeric values that can be chosen randomly, and the values of the `dict` would be the two numbers that go with that choice.  Something like this:

```
import random
# Random Pole Height
list = [11, 21, 9, 23, 13, 19, 27, 7]
random_pole_wid = random.choice(list)

data = {
    11: (11, 21),
    21: (21, 11),
    9: (9, 23),
    23: (23, 9),
    13: (13, 19),
    19: (19, 13),
    27: (27, 7),
    7: (7, 27),
}

if random_pole_wid in data:
    pole_a_wid, pole_b_wid = data[random_pole_wid]
else:
    print("The chosen value is not one of the expected choices.")
    pole_a_wid, pole_b_wid = 0, 0

print(pole_a_wid, pole_b_wid)
```